# Postgres Function not working while upgrading .NET Core

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

Postgres function not working while we upgraded our .net core and other packages to latest version. Earlier, the same code was working perfectly fine.

We are using function instead of stored procedure.

```cs
DbTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);

try
{
        using (DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.Transaction = transaction;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = Constants.StoredProcedure.SPNAME;
            command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("Param1", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer)
            { Value = val1 });
            command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("Param2", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar)
            { Value = val2 });
            command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("Param3", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar)
            { Value = val3 });
            var res = command.ExecuteScalar();
            transaction.Commit();
}}
```

Error - Npgsql.PostgresException: '42809: public.NotableEventUserModeratorJoinOrder(Param1 => integer, Param2 => character varying, Param3 => character varying) is not a procedure

We have commented line `command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;` and then receving error - PostgreSQL, Npgsql returning 42601: syntax error at

Answer (score 6):

It is a [documented breaking change](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/release-notes/7.0.html#a-namecommandtypestoredprocedure-commandtypestoredprocedure-now-invokes-procedures-instead-of-functions) in npgsql 7.

The [doc](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html#stored-functions-and-procedures) on the stored procedures / functions also says:

> Warning
>
> Starting with Npgsql 7.0, CommandType.StoredProcedure now invokes
> stored procedures, and not function as before. See the release notes
> for more information and how to opt out of this change.

And the two options are

1. disable the new feature

> When `NpgsqlCommand.CommandType` is set to `CommandType.StoredProcedure`,
> Npgsql now generates SQL for invoking a PostgreSQL stored procedure,
> and not a function, as before. To opt out of this breaking change and
> continue to invoke functions as before, enable the
> `Npgsql.EnableStoredProcedureCompatMode` AppContext switch as follows:
>
> `AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableStoredProcedureCompatMode", true);`

or

2. call your function with a regular `select`

`using var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT my_func(1, 2)", conn);`